# Old style numbers without fontspec

Tags: fonts, fontspec, documentation, oldstylenums

How do I use old style numbers *everywhere* without using `fontspec`? Or is it even possible? Where do I find the documentation for the fonts in the [LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/)?

**Minimum (Non)Working Example**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% Uncomment either of the following two lines:
%\usepackage[Numbers=OldStyle]{tgpagella}
%\usepackage[osf][tgpagella]

\begin{document}
  Hello World!
  1234567890
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2852/utilizing-oldstyle-figures-without-resorting-to-oldstylenums) question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `\oldstylenums{01234567890}` for specific cases. However, some font packages such as `mathpazo` which is palatino have options to set this automatically for text so that you do not need to type in the command explicitly, so you simply load the package normally, for example for Palatino is:

```
\usepackage[sc,osf]{mathpazo}
```

You can see some working examples with various fonts in this question [Palatino fonts and the number 713](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8204/palatino-fonts-and-the-number-713)

One of the problems in setting *oldstyle* numerals globally is that they look wrong in tables with a lot of numbers. A good solution to this problem was provided by TH in the answers to the above question.

If your font does not  have text figures built in; the `textcomp` package attempts to remedy this by effectively generating text figures from the currently-selected font.

Put `\usepackage{textcomp`} in your preamble. `textcomp` also allows you to use decimal points, properly formatted dollar signs, etc. within `\oldstylenums{}`.

Comment: Is it possible with `tgpagella`?

Comment: @Kit not sure, you need to read the tex-gyre docs:) However, see the edit above for more.

Comment: `\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}` is sufficient (the `osf` option includes the `sc` option).

Comment: @lockstep  Thanks, but my understanding is that the OP wanted to use the `tgpagella`, which I was not sure if it includes an option like mathpazo.

Comment: tgpagella does not have such an option -- but if you can tell the difference between tgpagella and mathpazo, good for you! Consider also `\usepackage[fulloldstylenums]{kpfonts}`.