# Use lining figures in longtable

Tags: longtable, oldstylenums

@TH. has shown a great way to use lining figures in tables:

> [Palatino fonts and the number 713](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8204/palatino-fonts-and-the-number-713)

Is there an equivalent for a longtable?
Because neither `@tabular` nor `@longtable` gives me lining figures in the longtable.
(*Since I will only use longtables in the appendix it would be also okay (quick & dirty) to set lining figures globally at that point where I start the appendix*)

mwe:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[sc,osf]{mathpazo}
\makeatletter
\preto\@tabular{\fontfamily{pplx}\selectfont}
\preto\@longtable{\fontfamily{pplx}\selectfont}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
text: 713

\begin{tabular}{c}
regular table\\
713
\end{tabular}

\begin{longtable}{c}
longtable\\
713 
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case of `longtable` macro `\LT@array` can be redefined:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[sc,osf]{mathpazo}
\makeatletter
\preto\@tabular{\fontfamily{pplx}\selectfont}
\preto\LT@array{\fontfamily{pplx}\selectfont}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
text: 713

\begin{tabular}{c}
regular table\\
713
\end{tabular}

\begin{longtable}{c}
longtable\\
713
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]